# Heisenbug: ansible.windows.win_user fails with "Illegal operation attempted on a registry key that has been marked for deletion."

Tags: ansible, windows-server-2019, packer

Using Packer to build an AMI based on Windows Server 2019, and Ansible as provisioner.

This is the `provisioners` part of my `packer-build.json`:

```json
    "provisioners": [
        {
            "type": "ansible",
            "playbook_file": "./provisioners/ansible/ansible_playbook.yml",
            "user": "Administrator",
            "use_proxy": false,
            "extra_arguments": ["-e", "ansible_winrm_server_cert_validation=ignore"]
        }
    ]
```

This is my `ansible_playbook.yml`:

```yaml
---
- name: Jenkins node playbook
  hosts: all
  tasks:
    - include_tasks: update_system.yml
    - include_tasks: install_dependencies.yml
    - include_tasks: create_user.yml
```

I can confirm that at least `update_system.yml` and `install_dependencies.yml` run successfully.

This is my `create_user.yml`:

```yaml
---

- name: Ensure user jenkins is present
  ansible.windows.win_user:
    name: jenkins
    password: ***REDACTED***
    state: present
    groups:
      - Users

.
.
.
```

I get an error at this point:

> amazon-ebs: TASK [Ensure user jenkins is present] ******************************************

> amazon-ebs: fatal: [default]: UNREACHABLE! => {"changed": false, "msg": "basic: Illegal operation attempted on a registry key that has been marked for deletion.  (extended fault data: {'transport_message': 'Bad HTTP response returned from server. Code 500', 'http_status_code': 500, 'wsmanfault_code': '2147943418', 'fault_code': 's:Receiver', 'fault_subcode': 'w:InternalError'})", "unreachable": true}

Googling "ansible Illegal operation attempted on a registry key that has been marked for deletion" did not yield anything useful.

While writing this question, I tried to reproduce the issue, and to get quicker results, I changed `ansible_playbook.yml` from

```yaml
---
- name: Jenkins node playbook
  hosts: all
  tasks:
    - include_tasks: update_system.yml
    - include_tasks: install_dependencies.yml
    - include_tasks: create_user.yml
```

to

```yaml
---
- name: Jenkins node playbook
  hosts: all
  tasks:
    - include_tasks: create_user.yml
    - include_tasks: update_system.yml
    - include_tasks: install_dependencies.yml
```

so putting `create_user.yml` first.

Result: the error could no longer be reproduced.

Then I restored to the original configuration, and I also no longer had the error.

That does not make any sense at all to me, and I don't trust it. Sounds like a [Heisenbug](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heisenbug) to me.

What is this error and how can I make absolutely sure that it doesn't occur again?

[@Semicolon](https://serverfault.com/users/340559/semicolon) asked in the comments for the contents of `update_system.yml` and `install_dependencies.yml`.

```yaml
---

- name: Install all critical and security updates
  win_updates:
    category_names:
      - CriticalUpdates
      - SecurityUpdates
    state: installed
  register: update_result

- name: Reboot host if required
  win_reboot:
  when: update_result.reboot_required
```

```yaml
---

- name: Install AWS CLI
  win_shell: Import-Module AWSPowerShell

- name: install the Win32-OpenSSH service
  win_chocolatey:
    name: openssh
    package_params: /SSHServerFeature
    state: present

- name: Install required software
  win_chocolatey:
    name: '{{ item }}'
    state: present
  loop:
    - openjdk11
    - maven
    - git
    - ghostscript
    - imagemagick
    - nodejs
    - nuget.commandline
    - visualstudio2017buildtools
```

Comment: If consistently repeatable with the sequence you have, and consistently avoidable with the modified sequence, it would be an unusual for somebody to offer an explaination without knowing the contents of either install_dependencies.yml or update_system,yml,

Comment: See edit. It is not consistently repeatable with the original sequence. I've done some further googling, and didn't find anything related to Ansible, but did find some vague references to the error in other contexts, with something something it being a feature of Windows to delete registry keys when a user is not logged in. As I haven't used Windows since Windows for Workgroups 3.11, I am unsure how to prevent that.

Comment: I've added the contents of `install_dependencies.yml` and `update_system,yml`, please tell me how they are related to the issue at hand.

Comment: I know this wont add any value for you, but I see this error often and rerunning the jobs without changing a single thing fixes the issue. I suspect that it has something to do with how unstable the winrm python module is. It seems as though it is very vulnerable to network instability.

Comment: fwiw https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/31030